# WebStorm not loading ~/.bashrc on terminal load on any NIX/OSX system

Tags: linux, macos, configuration, terminal, webstorm

WebStorm 10.0.2
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

WebStorm does not load ~/.bashrc on terminal load. Problem appears on all flavors of my nix/osx systems. There does not appear to be a setting to correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest and easiest solution was to edit the .profile and include the following

`# require /.bashrc for webstorm
. ~/.bashrc`

You will have to select the 'x' button in WebStorm on the terminal tab and then reopen it for this to take effect.